# Listen for changes inside form control of a nested form group

Tags: forms, angular, typescript, angular-forms

```
export class ApplyComponent implements OnInit {
    formApply: FormGroup;
    postCodeInput: boolean = true;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.formApply = this.fb.group({
            firstName: ["", Validators.required],
            currentUKAddress: this.fb.group({
                flat: ["", Validators.required],
                years: ["", Validators.required]
            })
        });
        this.onChanges();
    }

    onChanges(): void {
        ...
    }
```

I want to listen for changes in **years**. No matter what I tried inside `onChanges()` I cannot find why nothing works...
I tried:

```
- this.formApply.get('currentUKAddress.years').valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
            console.log('Form changes', data);
        })

 - this.formApply.controls.currentUKAddress.get('years').valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
            console.log('Form changes', data);
        })



- this.formApply.controls.currentUKAddress.controls['years'].valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
            console.log('Form changes', data);
        })
```

and other stuff as well. In all cases I am getting Typescript compiler error either:
**property does not exist on type AbstractControl**
or
**Object is possibly null**.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For some reason type checker is unable to make a right decision. So [Non-null assertion operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator) (!) came to my rescue:

```
this.formApply.get('currentUKAddress.years')!.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
            console.log('Form changes', data);
        })
```

works like a charm...

Answer (score 3):

```
 const year =  <FormControl>(this.formApply.get('currentUKAddress.years'));
year.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
            console.log('Form changes', data);
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

`ngOnChanges` is only useful for input/output variables.

If you want to listen to changes in your text (?) inputs, you must do

```
<input type="text" formControlName="flat" (input)="flatChangeListener($event)">
```

In your TS

```js
flatChangeListener(event) {
  // event should contain the input value.
}
```

Do this for the other one and you're good to go ! And if it's not a text input, please tell me so, the `(input)` would change in this case (for instance, it's `(change)` for a select)

Comment: What I cannot understand is why I am getting **Object is possibly null** with even `this.formApply.get('firstName')`

Comment: I have **NEVER** seen this error. Does your form works ?

Comment: what if you want to listen to changes in an input type 'checkbox' or if listen to changes in a <select> inside a <form>?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this ..

```
this.formApply.get('currentUKAddress').get('years').valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
            console.log('Form changes', data);
        })
```

Comment: This worked for me in a very similar problem. I think this should be the accepted answer, because it's very obvious what the code is doing and it's simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.frmParamsTit.get(['lugar']['pais']).valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
    data.pais=='GT'? this.verLdepartamento=true:this.verLdepartamento=false;
  });
```

Comment: Could you add more detail to your answer. I think this is what the author was already trying to do, and his problem had to do with the compiler throwing an error which he solved with the non nullable operator.

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same form structure and I did something like below:

```
this.formApply.controls.currentUKAddress.valueChanges.subscribe(
 currentUKAddress =>
    {
      console.log("years", currentUKAddress.years) // Here you can check whatever 
                                                   //  value is coming in years.

    }
 )
```

None of the above solutions worked for me. So I listened to currentUKAddress instead of years directly.

Hope this Idea helps someone.

*Angular version: 7*